# Doubt in analysing the motion of medium particles in longitudinal wave propagation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, acoustics, collision

Below is the link for the pic of my doubt.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Isx1S.jpg

There is some vibrating source at the left end of the long semi infinite tube and the medium is air. Suppose that the average velocity of the air without the sound source is $v_o$. The vibrating source having the amplitude such that it pushes only the first particle in the $+x$ direction to accelerate the first particle to velocity $v_1=v_o + v_{max}$.
This first particle then collides with the second particle. We always assume the collision between the air particles to be elastic (ideal gas approximation). As all the medium particles are identical, they have same mass. The second particles moves in $+x$ direction with $v_o$ We know that if same mass body collides with each other, they exchange their velocities. So after collision, the first particle will move with the velocity $v_o$ and the second particle will move with the velocity $v_1$. So, we can see that after first collision the particle moves in $+x$ direction. It will move away from the source. The vibrating source will see no particle to transfer the push. I think that first particle should move backwards so that the vibrating source will again push it forwards.

If we continue this thought for all particles of the medium. We can see that all the particles will move in $+x$ direction. There is no oscillation of the medium particles. Also in ideal gas approximation, we can't assume the particles to be on a spring such that if one particle gets displaced, then the spring will get deformed which applies force such that it can come back to its natural length. The particles are non-interacting in some sense. All the changes in velocity should come only through the elastic collision between the particles.

I think that I am missing something while analysing the sound wave propagation. Can somebody please help me.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose that the average velocity of the air without the sound source is $v_0$... I think that I am missing something while analysing the sound wave propagation. Can somebody please help me.

The average **velocity** of a tube of air with no bulk motion is 0. Instead, you seem to be taking an average (root-mean-square?) **speed**—which I agree is nonzero—but also assuming it's in the positive *x*-direction for some reason. This doesn't seem conducive to predictive modeling.

Instead, you might start by considering a particle at zero initial speed and use a more accurate schematic that shows other particles and the accompanying compression and rarefaction regions:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. If we consider initially the particles to be moving in random direction (consider one dimensional motion for simplicity). So when vibrator pushes the x1 particles, they will collide with x2 particles and exchange their velocities (due to elastic collision).

Comment: As a result, the x2 particles will move in +x direction and x1 particles will move randomly. Those x1 particles which has velocity in -x direction will move towards vibrator and then  the vibrator will again push them, they will collide with those x2 particles which gains velocity in -x direction (due to their collision with x3 particles) and the cycle continues.  So we can see that as time passes, there are less particles moving in -x direction.

Comment: As a result the vibrator will see decreasing density of particles as time passes. so sound propagation should eventually stops. But the solution of wave equation for semi- infinite tube suggests harmonic behaviour. I am not able to interpret it physically.

Comment: Make sure to incorporate the fact that particles bouncing off the retreating vibrator surface lose positive x-direction momentum. I don't see where you've addressed that yet.

Comment: The only way the particle will lose momentum in +x direction is by collision with other particles (ideal gas assumption). But as shown n my above replies, the number of particles in -x direction will continuously decrease.

Comment: If you ignore the surface actually driving the vibration, of course the analysis will produce a paradoxical or incorrect result.

Answer (score 0):

### Qualitative answer

**Short answer.**
The material particles of the fluid oscillate in time in a region of space very close to their base initial position, with amplitude and phase that depends on the position in space w.r.t. the wave number $k$, through the value of $\cos(k x_0)$.

[image]

**The main flaw in the question.**
The main flaw in your picture about pressure waves is represented in the attached picture: if it approximately represents the microscopical details of the gas, you're assuming that the gas is only present in the region close to the vibrating end of the tube, while vacuum (no particles) fills the remaining volume.

Without the forcing from the vibrating wall, this system resembles a Riemann problem in gas dynamics, where two homogeneous regions of the fluid are initially in contact.

### Quantitative answer

**1D linearized Euler equations.** The physical process of sound transmission in a straight pipe can be described by the isentropic 1-D Euler equations, linearized around the base state $P = P_{atm}$, $u = 0$, namely

$\partial_t P' + \rho c^2 \partial_x u' = 0$  (mass equation)
$\partial_t u' + \dfrac{1}{\rho} \partial_x P' = 0$  (momentum equation)

being $P(x,t) = P_{atm} + P'(x,t)$, $u(x,t) = 0 + u'(x,t)$ the pressure and the velocity field, $\rho$ is the density of the base state, $c$ is the speed of sound in the base state, namely

$c^2(\rho,s) = \left(\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial \rho}\right)_s(\rho,s)$$\qquad \text{so that} \qquad$$P' = \left(\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial \rho}\right)_s(\rho,s) \rho' = c^2(\rho,s) \rho'$.

If the pipe has open end in $x=L$ and the vibrating wall in $x=0$, the boundary conditions of the differential problem can be written as

$u'(0,t) = u_{wall}(t)$
$P'(L,t) = 0$

**From Euler equations to wave equation.**
Manipulation of Euler equations can provide us with wave equations for the velocity and the pressure fields

$\partial_{tt} u' - c^2 \partial_{xx} u' = 0$
$\partial_{tt} P' - c^2 \partial_{xx} P' = 0$

**Possible solution techniques of the Euler equations or the wave equation.**

The problem can be approached with several techniques:

- methods of characteristics
- separation of variables
- numerical methods
- ...

**Solution with separation of variables.**
To get a simple solution (even though it's not the most general one), we approach the problem using the method of separation of variables for the wave equation for the velocity field

$\partial_{tt} u' - c^2 \partial_{xx} u' = 0 \qquad$
with b.c.
$\qquad u'(0,t) = u_{wall}(t) = U_w \sin (\Omega t)$
$\quad \partial_x u'(L,t) = 0$,

having assumed here a harmonic function for the displacement of the moving wall. We write the solution as $u(x,t) = f(x) g(t)$, to get

$\ddot{g}(t) f(x) - c^2 g(t) f''(x) = 0$$\qquad \rightarrow \qquad$
$\dfrac{1}{c}\dfrac{\ddot g }{g} = \dfrac{f''}{f} = a = \text{const.}$

The constant of integration $A$ must be negative to avoid unphysical diverging solutions. We can call it $a = - k^2$ interpreting $k$ as the wave number of the spatial part of the solution $f(x)$, that reads

$f(x) = A \cos ( k x ) + B  \sin ( k x )$

The boundary conditions gives us

$u_w(t) = u(0,t) = g(t) A = U_w \sin (\Omega t)$
$0 = \partial_x u(x,L) = g(t) k \left[ -A \sin (kL) + B \cos (kL) \right]$$\quad \rightarrow \quad$$-A \sin (kL) + B \cos (kL) = 0$

If $\cos(kL) \ne 0 $, we can write $B = A \tan(kl)$. The expression of $g(t)$ provides us the relation between the wave number and the frequency of the wall oscillation

$k = \dfrac{\Omega}{c}$.

The solution of the wave equation for the velocity field reads

$u'(x,t) = g(t) [ A \cos(kx) + B \sin(kx) ] = $
$\qquad \quad = U_w \left[ \cos\left(\dfrac{\Omega}{c}x\right) + \tan\left(\dfrac{\Omega}{c} L\right) \sin\left(\dfrac{\Omega}{c}x\right) \right] \sin (\Omega t)$

while the pressure field can be retrieved using Euler equations that relates the pressure field with the velocity field, so that

$P'(X,t) = - \rho c U_w \left[ \sin\left(\dfrac{\Omega}{c}x \right) - \tan\left(\dfrac{\Omega}{c} L\right) \cos\left(\dfrac{\Omega}{c}x\right) \right] \cos (\Omega t)$

**Trajectory of the material particles.**
I choose here a forcing frequency $\Omega$ that gives $\tan \left(\frac{\Omega}{c} L\right) = 0$ to reduce some of the complexity of the problem.

Once we have the velocity field $u(x,t)$, we can find the trajectory of a material particle, integrating the equation

$\dot{X}(t) = u(X(t),t)$$\qquad \rightarrow \qquad$$\dfrac{d X}{dt} = U_w \cos\left(\dfrac{\Omega}{c}X(t) \right) \sin (\Omega t)$

that can be integrated using separation of variables

$\displaystyle \int_{x_0}^{x(t)}\dfrac{dX}{\cos\left(\dfrac{\Omega}{c}X \right)} = \int_{t_0}^{t} U_w \sin(\Omega t) dt $

as

$\ln \bigg| \dfrac{1+\sin (kx)}{\cos (kx)} \dfrac{\cos (k x_0)}{(1+\sin(k x_0)} \bigg| = \dfrac{U_w}{c} \left[ \cos(\Omega t) - \cos(\Omega t_0) \right]$

and thus

$\dfrac{1+\sin (kx)}{\cos (kx)}  = - \dfrac{1+\sin (kx_0)}{\cos (kx_0)} \exp\left(\dfrac{U_w}{c} \left[ \cos(\Omega t) - \cos(\Omega t_0) \right] \right)$

Assuming that the displacement of a single particle is "small" around its initial position $x_0$, we can eventually write the function $F(x) = \frac{1+\sin (kx)}{\cos (kx)}$ as a Maclaurin series around $x_0$, $F(x) \sim F(x_0) + F'(x_0) (x-x_0)$, with $F'(x) = k\frac{1+\sin (kx)}{\cos^2 (kx)}$ to get

$X(t) \sim x_0 - \dfrac{1}{k}\dfrac{\cos^2 (k x_0)}{1 + \sin (k x_0)} \dfrac{1+\sin (kx_0)}{\cos (kx_0)} \left\{-1 + \exp\left(\dfrac{U_w}{c} \left[ \cos(\Omega t) - \cos(\Omega t_0) \right] \right) \right\}$
$\qquad \ = x_0 - \dfrac{1}{k} \cos ( k x_0) \left\{-1 + \exp\left(\dfrac{U_w}{c} \left[ \cos(\Omega t) - \cos(\Omega t_0) \right] \right) \right\}$

Moreover, if we assume that the maximum velocity of the wall $U_w$ is much lower than the speed of sound $c$, $U_w \ll c$, we can approximate well the term $+1-\exp(a x)$ with its Taylor series $+1-exp{a x} \sim - ax$ and thus

$X(t) \sim x_0  - \cos ( k x_0) \dfrac{U_w}{\Omega} \left[ \cos(\Omega t) - \cos(\Omega t_0) \right] = x_0 + \cos ( k x_0) \dfrac{U_w}{\Omega} \left[ 1 - \cos(\Omega t) \right]$,

if we start from time $t_0 = 0$.

**Interpretation of the results.**
From the last expression, it should be clear that the material particles of the fluid oscillate in time in a region of space very close to their base initial position, with amplitude and phase that depends on the position in space w.r.t. the wave number $k$, through the value of $\cos(k x_0)$.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is somewhat equivalent to dominos falling. The front of the perturbation moves only in one direction and there is no elastic effect. The origin of your paradox is in the ill defined scale length of your "particles". I have the feeling that what you call a particle of gas is in fact an atom, but Physicists use another definition.

Let's assume that your gas is made of billiard balls which only interact through contact during the collision. Since there is no long range force between the particles, there is no restoring force, and a particle entering the gas from the right will experience endless collisions that will send it on a pseudo-random trajectory. There is absolutely no reason for it to oscillate back and forth. So clearly we cannot explain anything with our model.

No consider a fluid cell: i.e a small volume of gas containing a large enough number of particles to use statistical mechanics but small enough to be considered a point.  When the cell moves to the left, it increases the density of particles on the left and decreases it on the right. As a result, the net force on the cell (which is proportional to the number of collisions) is directed towards the right.
Using Newton's laws, the cell moves back to the right and exerts an opposing force toward the left.  Now we can explain the elastic properties of gas.

Non equilibrium Statistical mechanics uses three space scales:

1. The atomic scale

It is used to write down the interactions. For a gas containing N atoms, one has 2N+1 degrees of freedom and equations to solve.

2. The kinetic scale:

It uses the reduced one particle distribution function which depends on 7 variables: $f( \overrightarrow{r}, \overrightarrow{v} ,t) $

3. The fluid scale:

It is the scale where Navier Stokes equations are valid. Each field $ \rho,~P,~T,~ \overrightarrow{v}, S$ depends on four variables $ \overrightarrow{r} ,t$

The math to define the scales and the equations is really complex. Just keep in mind that when we are talking about a fluid cell, it is a small region of space containing a large number of atoms/molecules.

Answer (score 0):

Your analysis is correct for large masses, but it is not a correct analysis for sound in air.

The main thing that you are missing is that in air, the sound pressure wave is a small fluctuation riding on top of a lot of thermal action of the air molecules.  Even without sound the molecules are moving very fast and bumping into each other constantly.  Their mean free path and mean free time between collisions is very small.  This creates a very different dynamic than what you describe, and sound in air is better described by the ideas of pressure (which is an average parameter taken over many molecules), etc, from which the normal aspects of sound can be derived.

Specifically, then, in your model you don't have a restoring spring force, so that once a ball/molecule moves forward there's nothing pushing it back.  **In real air, it is the thermal motion of the molecules (which can also be thought of as a pressure) that drives the air molecules back into the lower pressure region following a sound wave pressure peak**.

There are a few additional things to note that may be of interest:

1. You might say, "A large mass is just a large version of a molecule, so why does a different physics apply for molecules than large masses?"  The answer to this is that thermal energy gives *energy* to each particle.  At room temperature this is a lot of energy for a small particle so it moves very fast, whereas it's not noticeable for large particles.  That is, large masses won't be pushed around by air molecules, but other air molecules will be.
2. The diagrams with dots (and especially moving dots) that other answers are showing represent the variation in density that is consistent with a sound wave, and these can be useful to understanding various aspects of sound waves, but I think they are confusing for this question because they are drawn to look like the positions of actual particles.  The positions and motions of the particles look nothing like this, because it is the *random motions* of the particles that drives the pressure wave (in particular the restoring motion, that is the core of this question), and these diagrams don't show that random motion (and instead show random positions and correlated motion).